# Print out all remaining lines in Perl

Tags: perl, loops

I'm not new to Perl, but I use it far too rarely to learn everything one needs to remember. Now I'm writing a simple script that iterates over each line of a file and makes a few changes as needed. The interesting part looks like this:

```
while (<>)
{
    $modified_line = ... # modify current line as required
    print $modified_line; # print out the modified line
}
```

This is all working fine, but I only need to apply a few changes in the beginning of the file, and I don't like the idea of iterating over every single line only for that.
I would rather like to break out of the loop upon a particular condition and print out the rest of the input file unchanged. Is this possible?

```
while (<>)
{
    $modified_line = ... # modify current line as required
    print $modified_line; # print out the modified line
    last if /^\[.*]$/; # break out if line is enclosed in []
}
# how to print out the rest of the file unchanged here?
```

Comment: `while(<>){...; last if no_further_modifications} print while <>;`

Comment: ITYM `last if /^\[.*\]$/`

Comment: The problem with the `next unless` is you have to ask the question, "what's the alternative to `unless`?" The answer is it goes to the next statement, which is around to the top of the `while` loop. Thus, the `next` method will have no real effect.

Comment: @Borodin thanks, should be like that.

Comment: @mbratch in fact, I just meant to break out of the loop, but that's not my point here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add

```
print while <>;
```

It still reads through all of the rest of the file — it has to to be able to copy the rest of the data to the output — but it's really not a problem.

Comment: @mob: That needlessly reads the whole of the rest of the file into memory before printing it. It's unlikely to matter, but it's pointless to avoid the optimisation when it is so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your example will just continue regardless. You want to exit if the condition is true, so something like:

```
while (<>)
{
    $modified_line = ... # modify current line as required
    print $modified_line; # print out the modified line
    last if /^\[.*]$/; # break out if line is enclosed in []
}
```